# model.onDidChangeContent vs editor.onKeyUp in monaco editor for validation and autosave

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events, monaco-editor, autosave

I am wondering the difference between these two method: [`model.onDidChangeContent`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html#ondidchangecontent) vs [`editor.onKeyUp`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.icodeeditor.html#onkeyup)

So for example, I got two scenarios here:

- Doing simple syntax validation when user editing on the editor
- Autosave functionality

One thing I am pretty sure is I have to debounce the change (say 500ms) and then call related event handler. However the problem here is i am not sure when event i should use to accomplish these two functionally. Looks like `onChange(onInput)` and `onKeyUp` most of the time show same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event `onDidChangeContent` is also triggered for other changes like code actions (e.g. selecting a completion item) or commands (e.g. paste), not only key events. So it's clearly the better choice.